# Is there a way to change the name of the robot NAO v6?

Tags: nao-robot

I did a factory reset on the NAO v6 robot, because I wanted to change its name, but unfortunately I could not because I did not find any option, is there any way to change its name, or is the name a standard robot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an API for that: [ALSystem.setRobotName](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/core/alsystem-api.html#ALSystemProxy::setRobotName__ssCR).
After setting the robot name, you need to reboot the robot if you want Choregraphe find it by its name.

That means that you can connect to the robot using SSH, and type:

```sh
qicli call ALSystem.setRobotName "My robot's name"
sudo reboot
```

Comment: You can add a "Python Script" Box in Choregraphe and put the following code in the "onLoad" function: 
`from naoqi import ALProxy                                                                   
alSystemProxy = ALProxy("ALSystem", "your ip-adress of robot", 9559)                        
alSystemProxy.setRobotName("new robot name")`

Answer (score 0):

You can also type its ip address in your browser and directly change the robot's name.

Comment: No, this is not possible in my GUI.

Comment: This was true for Nao v5, v6 doesn't seem to have that setting anymore.